# how to broadcast the content of a RDD efficiently

Tags: apache-spark

so I have this need to broadcast some related content from a RDD to all worker nodes, and I am trying to do it more efficiently.

More specifically, some RDD is created dynamically in the middle of the execution, to broadcast some of its content to all the worker nodes, an obvious solution would be to traverse its element one by one, and create a list/vector/hashmap to hold the needed content while traversing, and then broadcast this data structure to the cluster.

This does not seems to be a good solution at all since the RDD can be huge and it is distributed already, traversing it and creating some array/list based on the traversal result will be very slow.

So what would be a better solution, or best practice for this case? Would it be a good idea to run a SQL query on the RDD (after changing it to a dataFrame) to get the needed content, and then broadcast the query result to all the worker nodes?

thank you for your help in advance!

**The following is added after reading Varslavans' answer:**

a RDD is created dynamically and it has the following content:

```
[(1,1), (2,5), (3,5), (4,7), (5,1), (6,3), (7,2), (8,2), (9,3), (10,3), (11,3),  ...... ]
```

so this RDD contains key-value pairs. What we want is to collect all the pairs whose value is > 3. So pair (2,5), (3,5), (4,7), ..., will be collected. Now, once we collected all these pairs, we would like to broadcast them so all the worker nodes will have these pairs.

Sounds like we should use `collect()` on the RDD and then broadcast... at least this is the best solution at this point.

Thanks again!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all - you don't need to traverse RDD to get all data. There is API for that - `collect()`.

Second: Broadcast is not the same as distributed.

- In broadcast - you have all the data on each node
- In Distributed - you have different parts of a whole on each node

RDD is distributed by it's nature.

Third: To get needed content you can either use [RDD API](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.2.0/api/scala/index.html#package) or convert it to DataFrame and use SQL queries. It depends on the data you have. Anyway contents of the result will be RDD or DataFrame and it will also be distributed. So if you need data locally - you `collect()` it.

**Btw from your question it's not possible to understand what you exactly want to do and it looks like you need to read Spark basics. That will give you much answers :)**

Comment: Thank you for answering the question... see the added content I added to the question ... so sounded like collect() is the thing to do.

Comment: Actually if there are too much data after filtering pairs - `collect` might fail. And generally `collect` is a bad practice. There are API like `join` on `RDD` that might do same as `broadcast` in case if there is a lot of data.